# How to convert to system datetime format from a string?

Tags: c#, datetime

I need to convert a string datetime format to a DateTime field which should be in system Datetime format?
I've tried Convert.ToDateTime, DateTime.Parse, DateTime.ParseExact but all of them convert to **dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss** format.

My string is in **yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm** format.

I was trying TryParseExact and specifying the culture also but I just couldn't understand that how it works. Below is the code that I am trying and my item.CreationDate is in **"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"** format

```
DateTime dateTime;  
bool isSuccess1 = DateTime.TryParseExact(item.CreationDate, "yyyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime);
DateTime result = dateTime;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A `DateTime` object doesn't have a *format*. It's a number. You *present* it in a specific format, in a specific Culture format (or the InvariantCulture), when needed. To use `ParseExact`, `TryParseExact` you need to provide a format (or formats) that describes the input. Don't confuse the presentation with the actual data.

Comment: Post your `item` and `CreationDate` data structure. No one can answer you without it.

Comment: Is `isSuccess1` true or false? If `true`, then the parsing succeeded. Now, what is `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` set to? Is it `en-US`? If not, there's a good chance that when you inspect the DateTime object value, it's *presented* using the current Culture definition format. But that's just what `DateTime.ToString()` generates.

Comment: @tushargoyal1309 - If you look at the source for `DateTime` you'll find this field - `private ulong dateData;` - and that's all that `DateTime` uses to store a date/time. There is no format. It's just a `ulong`.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. **If I can't copy and paste it into https://dotnetfiddle.net/ and run it without modification, it isn't yet a [mcve].** _Also, if you are going to remove some of the `yyyyy`, consider removing all of them._ :)

Comment: Is the type of `item.CreationDate` really a `string`? It has to be for your posted code to compile. (Try)Parse converts the string-input to a DateTime output, using the supplied format to make sense of the string. As mentioned before, the resulting DateTime doesn't have a format - the value you see is the result of a .ToString() conversion (for ex. by the debugger)

Answer (score 1):

Can it be this easy? - `yyyyy-MM-dd HH:mm` has 5 `y`s in your example, not 4.

Answer (score 0):

When you convert a string to DateTime you must state what format the input is in (as you have). If the conversion succeeded the DateTime object will hold the data for all the date parts (years, months, days etc.) and if you want to view them as a date again you must state what format you want to see them in. When using [DateTime.TryParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=netframework-4.8) it's worth noting that if the conversion fails it will set the value to the [DateTime.MinValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.minvalue?view=netframework-4.8).

There are various ways of showing the date again. The most common is stating the custom format for the date as a string. Another way is to use a [standard format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings).

```
var creationDate = "2020-04-13 13:23";

DateTime.TryParseExact(creationDate, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime dateTime);

var myCulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");

if(dateTime > DateTime.MinValue)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Your custom format date is: " + dateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"));
    Console.WriteLine("Your standard format date is: " + dateTime.ToString("g", myCulture));
}
```

When you put this into a console app the results are like this:

[image]

With some of the standard format ones you will need to define the culture as it will be different for something like the en-US compared to something like zh-CN. In my case I used 'en-GB'. [Here's a list of the accepted culture codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/rest-services/common-parameters-and-types/supported-culture-codes).